# DiagrammeR - create_graph and residual covariances

Tags: r, graphviz, r-lavaan, diagrammer, semplot

I found a really great [post](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/78926_5aa94ae32fae49f3a384ce885744ef4a.html) about converting `lavaan` output using `DiagrammeR`. However, the version of `DiagrammeR` used in this post is version `0.6` and I am running into some troubles in trying to reproduce the code for version `0.8` (http://rich-iannone.github.io/DiagrammeR/docs.html).

With some very minor changes, the code goes like this

First fit a SEM with `lavaan`

```
library("stringr")
library("lavaan")
library("DiagrammeR")
library("dplyr")
library("semPlot")

 model <- '
 # latent variables
 ind60 =~ x1 + x2 + x3
 dem60 =~ y1 + y2 + y3 + y4
 dem65 =~ y5 + y6 + y7 + y8
 # regressions
 dem60 ~ ind60
 dem65 ~ ind60 + dem60
 # residual covariances
  y1 ~~ y5
  y2 ~~ y4 + y6
  y3 ~~ y7
  y4 ~~ y8
  y6 ~~ y8
'

fit <- growth(model, data = PoliticalDemocracy)

semPaths(fit, intercept = FALSE, whatLabel = "est",
         residuals = FALSE, exoCov = FALSE)
```

Now this is the code proposed in the [post](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/78926_5aa94ae32fae49f3a384ce885744ef4a.html)

```
paths <- fit %>%
  parameterestimates %>%
  select(lhs, op, rhs, est)

# Latent variables are left-hand side of "=~" lines
latent <- paths %>%
  filter(op == "=~") %>%
  select(nodes = lhs) %>%
  distinct %>%
  mutate(shape = "circle")

# Manifest variables are not latent variables
`%not_in%` <- Negate(`%in%`)
manifest <- paths %>%
  filter(op != "~1", lhs %not_in% latent$nodes) %>%
  select(nodes = lhs) %>%
  distinct %>%
  mutate(shape = "square")

# Nodes are prepared
node_set <- combine_ndfs(latent, manifest)

# Edges will be labeled by the parameter estimates
all_paths <- paths %>%
  filter(op != "~1") %>%
  mutate(label = round(est, 2)) %>%
  select(-est)

# Factor loadings are the paths in the "=~" lines
loadings <- all_paths %>%
  filter(op == "=~") %>%
  mutate(edge_from = lhs, edge_to = rhs, style = "dashed") %>%
  select(edge_from, edge_to, style, label)

regressions <- all_paths %>%
  filter(op == "~") %>%
  rename(edge_to = lhs, edge_from = rhs) %>%
  mutate(style = "solid") %>%
  select(edge_from, edge_to, style, label)

edge_set <- combine_edfs(loadings, regressions)
```

So far, so good.

The errors come here

```
# Combine edges and nodes
my_graph <- graphviz_graph(
  nodes = node_set,
  edges_df = edge_set,
  graph_attrs = c("ranksep = 1"))

# We can plot the graph directly
graphviz_render(my_graph)
```

In the doc of `DiagrammeR`, it is said that "renamed functions `graphviz_graph` and `graphviz_render` to `create_graph` and `render_graph`".

However, making this change does not work

```
my_graph <- create_graph(
  nodes = node_set,
  edges_df = edge_set,
  graph_attrs = c("ranksep = 1"))
```

Any idea why?

Other question. In this post, this code does not seem to plot the *residual co-variances*. Any idea how to plot *residual co-variances* with `DiagrammeR`?

Thank you